# How can I insert a PHP multidimensional array in MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I don't understand how I can insert data from a PHP multi0dimensional array into a MySQL db.

Here is the code from my page:

```
$stato_porte = shell_exec("porte_lista.sh > ../tmp/stato_porte.txt");
$numero_porte = (int)shell_exec("cat ../tmp/stato_porte.txt | grep 'Giga\|Vlan' | wc -l");

for ($i = 1; $i <= $numero_porte; $i++)
{
    $stato_porta[$i] = trim(shell_exec(" cat ../tmp/stato_porte.txt | grep 'Giga\|Vlan' | awk  'FNR == ".$i." {print  $1}'"));
    if ($stato_porta[$i] == "*") 
    {
        $interfaccia[0][$i] = trim(shell_exec(" cat ../tmp/stato_porte.txt | grep 'Giga\|Vlan' | awk  'FNR == ".$i." {print  $2}'"));
        for ($a = 1; $a <= 3; $a++)
        {
            $interfaccia[1][$i] = trim(shell_exec(" cat ../tmp/stato_porte.txt | grep 'Giga\|Vlan' | awk  'FNR == ".$i." {print  $7}'"));
            $interfaccia[2][$i] = trim(shell_exec(" cat ../tmp/stato_porte.txt | grep 'Giga\|Vlan' | awk  'FNR == ".$i." {print  $9}'"));
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        $interfaccia[0][$i] = trim(shell_exec(" cat ../tmp/stato_porte.txt | grep 'Giga\|Vlan' | awk  'FNR == ".$i." {print  $1}'"));
        for ($a = 1; $a <= 3; $a++)
        {
            $interfaccia[1][$i] = trim(shell_exec(" cat ../tmp/stato_porte.txt | grep 'Giga\|Vlan' | awk  'FNR == ".$i." {print  $6}'"));
            $interfaccia[2][$i] = trim(shell_exec(" cat ../tmp/stato_porte.txt | grep 'Giga\|Vlan' | awk  'FNR == ".$i." {print  $8}'"));
        }
    }
}
```

In a multidimensional array "$interfaccia" i put in position [0][n] all Interface name of a switch, in position [1][n] i put all rx state of all interface and in position [2][n] i put all tx state of all interface.

In mysql i have this table:

```
MariaDB [network_devices]> describe data_interfaces;
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type            | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id          | int(6) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| device      | varchar(30)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| interface   | varchar(30)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| tx          | varchar(50)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| rx          | varchar(50)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| reg_date    | timestamp       | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
```

The field "device" is inserted with a static variable but how can I insert data from a multi-dimensional array?

To make it more clear, if I print an array via code:

```
for ($b = 1; $b <= $numero_porte; $b++)
{
    echo "Interfaccia: ".$interfaccia[0][$b];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "TX: ".$interfaccia[1][$b];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "RX: ".$interfaccia[2][$b];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

the output is:

```
Interfaccia: Vlan1
TX: 0
RX: 0
Interfaccia: Vlan7
TX: 0
RX: 0
Interfaccia: Vlan70
TX: 0
RX: 0
Interfaccia: Vlan1000
TX: 0
RX: 0
Interfaccia: Vlan2012
TX: 1000
RX: 1000
Interfaccia: GigabitEthernet1/0/1
TX: 5542000
RX: 5584000
Interfaccia: GigabitEthernet1/0/2
TX: 0
RX: 9000
Interfaccia: GigabitEthernet1/0/3
TX: 0
RX: 1000
Interfaccia: GigabitEthernet1/0/4
TX: 0
RX: 1000
```

.
.
.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Did you post your query attempt?

Comment: I'm not sure if my syntax is correct, but IF the following snippet works, it is much DRYer.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/16646276a9e0c42e8ec8ce0d8f58ed4a85f8b664

Comment: I've seen a lot of wild, unruly code on Stack Overflow, but this code is 10/10 totally berserk. This is wrong on several levels, but primarily because PHP is not fancy shell scripting, don't treat it like this. Use native functions whenever possible. This creates an unbelievable amount of shell calls for no reason, something that creates  a huge security risk.

Comment: Use functions like [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to process your file. Use [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to find out how many lines are in your file after using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split on lines. If you're using PHP, *use PHP*.